# Compute p-value for 2x2 table directly

Tags: chi-squared-test, contingency-tables

I just saw someone [compute a p-value](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=16483049) directly for a contingency table. Let's assume we have the observations $a$ and $\bar{a}$, and $b$ and $\bar{b}$. Obviously, $N = a + \bar{a} + b + \bar{b}$. The question was if there is a significant difference between $a$ and $b$.

The equation they used is (as far as I can tell)

$ 1 - \big(1 - \frac{a + b}{N}\big)^{a + b} - (a + b)\big(\frac{a + b}{N}\big)\big(1 - \frac{a + b}{N}\big)^{a + b - 1}.$

The result seems to be correct, I checked with Fisher's exact test in R.

What equation did they use? I am unable to find anything resembling this equation. What I find so intriguing is that they computed the p-value directly, apparently without using the distribution of a test statistic.

Comment: For anyone who might come across this, note that the HN poster [added their reasoning in a new post](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=16487404).